# Adding new Illustrator Script Ruler Units

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to add custom ruler units in Illustrator via script. I am using latest version of the Illustrator that is 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can just change units while adding new document and units can be from the following list

```
Centimeters 
Qs
Inches 
Pixels
Millimeters
Picas
Points
```

For reference, Pg. No. 252 from the following link

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/illustrator/pdf/Illustrator_Scriptin_Reference_JavaScript_cc.pdf

Comment: Thanks for sharing the reference. This is useful for the future work.